# Adding metadata to .rset file

Tags: metadata, nitf

I am was wondering if it is possible to view and add metadata to an R-Set file, converted from a NITF file https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/rsetwrite.html.

With NITFs, I am able to use GDAL to work with metadata. This does not seem to be possible with R-Sets as I am getting the error `ERROR 6: The HDF5 driver does not support update access to existing datasets.`

So far, I have not seen much information online about R-Sets. Is anybody aware of any resources that can point me in the right direction?